# Is it possible get a list of defects with state changed in the last day using the Lookback API

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I need to get a list of all defects that had its schedule state changed in the last day. I managed to get all the changes in the last day, but that brings ANY changes made to defects - if someone changed the owner of a defect, that will be returned as well. I just want a list of snapshots that were the result of Schedule State changes. Is that possible with the Lookback API?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work I think, in combination with your existing date range code:

```
{
    "find": {
       "_TypeHierarchy": "Defect"
       "_PreviousValues.ScheduleState": { "$lte": "Accepted" }, //where accepted is your last state
    },
    "fields": ["ScheduleState", "Name", "_PreviousValues.ScheduleState"],
    "hydrate": ["ScheduleState", "_PreviousValues.ScheduleState"]
}
```